# Trap MSAccess Link Table Errors

Tags: ms-access

In Access 2013 I have a linked table going to a SQLServer table. In SQL that table has a trigger that RAISERROR in some situations. My problem is when a user tries to save a row that causes an error to fire all they see is a generic message that says "ODBC--insert on a linked table failed."  I'm hoping I cantrap that error event, parse the SQL error and display a more user friendly MsgBox message that explains why their record couldn't be saved.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Access doesn't expose any method by which to trap a server-side error on a linked table, so without bypassing linked tables altogether and performing [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operations via ADO in a form, the answer is "No."

Had MS not removed .ADP support from Access 2013, I might have said "Use an ADP file", since ADPs passed on the specifics of the error in response to server-side errors.

If you wanted to use ADO for CRUD, you'd trap the various Before... events for Insert, Update and Delete, and in those events you could trap the errors in ADO.